# Best practice to create chat application with private rooms

Tags: android, ios, meteor, mobile, react-native

I'm trying to build chat application with private rooms (new to mobile application) .

The user can create new room with unique id/link and other users can enter the room only by using the id/link.

I'm using React-Native for the client side but i'm really confused what I should use for the server and what is the best practice for this situation.

I have thinking of something like this - the user create a room and then the server create table with the following data:

```
{
    "id",
    "room-id",
    "room-name",
    "users": {
        "foo",
        "bar"
    }
}
```

and the room-id is what I give to the users.

I don't know which technology or library I should use if I want this application to run on both ios and android, I have read about Meteor and Firebase but again i'm not sure.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Styx I agree with you, but then I asked myself, "Ok, where would one go to ask this question?"  Reddit?

Comment: @conarch Google, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinionated answer, but I'll make it anyway.

Meteor is a good solution for implementing chat, because of its reactivity.

It is a very simple exercise to build a chat interface, and it works very well. Meteor has support for IOS and Android too, and the build system makes that relatively easy.

Many Meteor apps have chat as a feature, which backs up this recommendation. Other technologies can do it too, but as far as I know there would be much more work involved in doing it